# How to detect the terminal that is running python?

Tags: python, cmd, cygwin

I've already tried sys.platform, platform.system() and os.name but none of them return something related to cygwin (I always get win32, Windows and nt as output). Maybe because my python was installed on windows (8.1) and not through cygwin.
I need to detect  if my python file is being executed by cygwin or cmd.

Comment: So interactive or by script?

Comment: You could do this in a hacky way. You could attempt to execute /bin/sh which will execute in Cygwin but not in DOS. You could do the other way around and attempt to run dir which would only work under DOS

Comment: You need to look at your parent process, something like psutil should do it https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil

Comment: You might be able to find an environment variable that is peculiar to each environment, then use `os.environ`.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to care about this?

Comment: The title is somewhat misleading; the "terminal" topic is (AFAIK) seldom used in Windows, and Linux people think of something else (a logical device rather than a command processor). This is more about the special case of Cygwin which runs under Windows but in many respects looks like Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin uses Linux-style paths; thus you might be able to check the path separator:

```
import sys
import os.path

def running_cygwin():
    return sys.platform == 'win32' and os.path.sep == '/'
```

(I don't have a Cygwin here, so this is untested.)

Comment: This is wrong, Cygwin Python has `sys.platform == 'cygwin'`.

Comment: Paulo says he has checked `sys.platform`; so this is probably not true for all versions ...

Comment: I think there is a confusion here between "a terminal running Python" and "Python Cygwin". He was probably running Windows Python inside Cygwin prompt (in which case the thing to check for would have been `sys.stdout.isatty()`).